# Trying to troubleshoot a JSON with an array within an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm trying to troubleshoot my code, which has a array within an array, and then I want to retrieve all of the ID values inside it

```
private TextView tvData;
private ImageView imgtest;
String ChampionName;
String ChampionNameInLowerCase;
String item2;
String item3;
String Booked;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);
    imgtest = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    // http://api.champion.gg/champion/Ekko/

    new JSONTask().execute("http://api.champion.gg/champion/Ekko/");
}


public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;



        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(finalJson);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject finalObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                ChampionName = finalObject.getString("key");
                String role = finalObject.getString("role");
                String items = finalObject.getString("items");

                JSONObject ItemArray = new JSONObject(items);
                item2 = ItemArray.getString("mostGames");
                JSONObject ItemArray2 = new JSONObject(item2);
               item3 = ItemArray2.getString("items");

                JSONArray jsonarray2 = new JSONArray(item3);

                for (int j=0;j<jsonarray2.length();j++) {
                    JSONObject finalObject2 = jsonarray.getJSONObject(j);

                    Booked = finalObject2.getString("id");
                }

                return ChampionName + role + item3 + Booked;
                }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tvData.setText(result);

        ChampionNameInLowerCase = ChampionName.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "");;

        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.kripzy.url:drawable/" + ChampionNameInLowerCase+"_square_0", null ,null);
        imgtest.setImageResource(id);




    }

}
}
```

And then more closely the code up for question is this section;

```
JSONArray jsonarray2 = new JSONArray(item3);

                for (int j=0;j<jsonarray2.length();j++) {
                    JSONObject finalObject2 = jsonarray.getJSONObject(j);

                    Booked = finalObject2.getString("id");
                }

                return ChampionName + role + item3 + Booked;
                }
```

When the code directly above is added, it gives an error

```
   org.json.JSONException: No value for id
```

When I delete that small snippet of code, the code produces

[image]

Comment: what is the the json response you are trying to parse??

Comment: call `jsonObj.getInt("id")` instead?

Comment: Its in the code but here it is - http://api.champion.gg/champion/Ekko/

Comment: and what are the values you want from this response??

Comment: i want, "key", "role, "items" ( and the array of data of "id and" name" inside it),

Comment: Is it supposed to be jsonarray.getJSONObject(j) instead if jsonarray2 ?

Comment: Well id is int not a string, my first guess. Try getting it as an int.

Comment: Changing it to an integer still has the same outcome, no text appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here `Booked = finalObject2.getString("id");` use `Booked = finalObject2.getInt("id");`

and by the way you can use 
`JSONObject finalObject2 = jsonarray.getJSONObject(jsonarray2.length()-1);` instead the the `for (int j=0;j<jsonarray2.length();j++)`

Comment: Changing it to an integer still has the same outcome, no text appears

Comment: try what @Julius Ada answer `JSONObject finalObject2 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(jsonarray2.length()-1);`

Comment: Hello, this does infact work however, it only returns the last id value eg; http://i.imgur.com/QKpF8YQ.png

Comment: in your code you override the value for `Booked` every time in the loop. so i guess that is your  purpose.
so you can do `  for (int j=0;j<jsonarray2.length();j++) {
                    JSONObject finalObject2 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(j);

                    Booked += finalObject2.getString("id")+" ";
                }  `

Answer (score 0):

In the for-loop where you iterate over jsonarray2 you access jsonarray instead of jsonarray2 to get your JSONObject.